# Override the Object.toString() Method with a default interface method in Java

Tags: java, overriding

I have an interface with `default String toString() {/*code*/}` as one of the members. when compiling I get the error:

```
Test.java:63: error: default method toString in interface TestObj overrides a member of java.lang.Object
                default String toString()
```

Trying to use `@Override` yields the same error. Is there anyway I can override toString() in this situation?

Comment: Essentially, no, you can't. This is explicitly forbidden. See the linked question.

Comment: Short answer: no.  Long answer: noooooo.